# How to Get Cities Data instead of Countries in Google Webmaster tools Query Search

Tags: google-search-console, geolocation, geotargeting

Under the performance review, google webmaster tool is showing the countries. Is there any way we can check the impression/ clicks breakup based on cities instead of countries.

Answer (score 1):

You can't currently filter Google webmaster data by city or state.

If you have Google Analytics set up then you can get some similar information. Go to **Acquisition > Overview** then click the traffic source you want to investigate.

Once the page loads up you can add a secondary dimension by clicking the drop down just above the table. In the search box type 'City' and click on the shown option.

The resulting table will show you all the cities you've received visitors from.